# Loop Cut and Slide Hotkey Not Working

Tags: modeling, mesh

I seem to run into this issue randomly and I'm not sure what causes it. Sometimes when creating a new project or loading an existing project, Ctrl+R will not create a loop cut on my mesh. I've tried the following:

- I've confirmed I have "Select Box" selected in edit mode
- I've confirmed my keybinding is correct
- I've confirmed I'm using the Blender keybinding preset
- I've confirmed that both my Ctrl and R keys work
- I've tried loading factory settings
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Blender

Even when I create a new project, I can't create a loop cut on the default cube.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, could you post an example screenshot of a mesh you are trying to loop cut and it fails. Sometimes when modelling with N-Gons, the algorithm can't define the flow of the loop cut and it doesn't work

Comment: Your first bullet point might be where you're getting tripped up since your select mode would not normally be part of troubleshooting an issue like this.

Comment: Loopcut only works in Edit Mode.